# Run a chain animation on different selectors by clicking once on a button

Tags: html, css, animation, css-animations

I am trying to run 2 CSS3 animations by clicking on a button.
The first animation makes the button rotate and disappear and the second animation changes a second button,and makes it appear(opacity changed from 0.5 to 1) and changes its height.

The problem is that only the first animation runs.
The first animation name is

> q1leave

and the second animation name is

> q2show

.
To run the first animation i use  `#btnq1:target` on CSS and to run the second animation i use  `#btnq1:target #btnq2a`

See below my code:

HTML code

```
<div id="q1">
    <div class="q1once">
        <a href="#btnq1"><button type="button" name="" value="" id="btnq1">Click to disappear and then change a different element </button></a>
    </div>
</div>

<button type="button" name="" value="" id="btnq2a">Must change</button>
```

CSS code

```
#q1 {
    height:100%;
}
.q1once {
    width:20%;
    height:15%;
    position:absolute;
    left:-50%;
    animation-name:q1;
    animation-delay:3s;
    animation-iteration-count:1;
    animation-duration:1.5s;
    animation-fill-mode:forwards;
}
#btnq1:target {
    animation-name:q1leave;
    animation-iteration-count:1;
    animation-duration:4s;
    animation-fill-mode:forwards;
}
#btnq1:target #btnq2a {
    animation-name:q2show;
    animation-iteration-count:1;
    animation-delay:4s;
    animation-duration:4s;
    animation-fill-mode:forwards;
}
@keyframes q1 {
    50% {
        transform:translate(440%) scaleX(3);
    }
    100% {
        transform:translate(450%) scale(1.5, 2);
    }
}
@keyframes q1leave {
    0% {
        transform:rotate(0deg);
        opacity:1;
    }
    100% {
        opacity:0;
        transform:rotate(360deg);
    }
}
@keyframes q2show {
    100% {
        opacity:1;
        height:200px;
    }
}
#btnq2a {
    opacity:0.5;
}
```

You can my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RKYa4/15/) as well.
I would like to solve it using only CSS3, but i will accept other solutions using JS, jquery or other. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: You are targeting `#btnq2a` as though it were a child of `#btnq1`.

Comment: @David Can i target #btnq2a as is? Meaning if they have no relationship(child, sibling or other)?

Comment: CSS targets relatively, from parent->child->grandchild, etc., so unless they have a relationship, CSS cannot select them relative to each other.

Comment: So the solution will involve JS/jQuery.

Comment: @David or if i make them relatives :). right?

Comment: If you figure out a way to make the second button be a child of the :#target element, then yes. It can be done.

Comment: @David can you help on that?

Comment: You could make them siblings but they'll both be affected by the opening animation. `#btnq1:target  + #btnq2a` http://jsfiddle.net/willthemoor/RKYa4/16/

Comment: @Will You are right but this is a first step for me to figure out a solution, thank you!

Comment: @Will I think i could add multiple classes for each element in order to control them better

Comment: why not use JS to toggle classes on click?

Comment: @Will Good idea. I didn't know i could that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way would be to use JavaScript to add a class to the second target whenever the first one is clicked.

```
var btn1 = document.getElementById('btnq1');
var btn2 = document.getElementById('btnq2a');
btn1.addEventListener('click', makeActive);

function makeActive(){
    var className = ' ' + btn2.className + ' ';
    // from SO Question #14615712
    if ( ~className.indexOf(' active ') ) {
        btn2.className = className.replace(' active ', ' ');
    } else {
        btn2.className += ' active ';
    }              
}
```

Or jQuery if you prefer:

```
$('#btnq1').on('click', function () {
    $('#btnq2a').toggleClass('active');
});
```

Then, adjust your CSS selector a bit.

```
#btnq2a.active {
    animation-name:q2show;
    animation-iteration-count:1;
    animation-delay:4s;
    animation-duration:4s;
    animation-fill-mode:forwards;
}
```

Here's an updated [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/willthemoor/RKYa4/18/)